# Can't connect from any active directory Windows PC to a Samba share with IP address, only with host name

Tags: active-directory, ldap, samba, network-share, sles

Ok, this one is a bit surreal:

We have an all Windows network with Active Directory  that has the domain controller server, a file server and a database server. Recently we had to add a SUSE Enterprise Server to the network to serve a Linux specific application and some files related to that app.

I added the server do the domain as instructed in the [SUSE support page](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=7022002) and configured the share folders. All computers in the network were able to access \\SLES12\ShareFolder without any issue, all authentication was being managed by the AD DC and everything was working flawlessly or so I thought.

Today somebody came to me and said that the Samba share was unavailable. I tested \\SLES12\ShareFolder and it was Ok but the person kept insisting that the share was unavailable so I VNCed to the workstation and sure enough \\192.168.1.205\ShareFolder is returning a 0x80004005 error with **Windows cannot access.**

The closest solution that I found to a similar problem was [this answer in superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/1241871) but it was related to a Windows share.

All the other shares in Windows servers in our network are accessible either by IP or hostname so I'm somewhat convinced that this is a problem in the Samba configuration but I don't know what could it be, son any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are the NTLMv2/SMB2 settings for both Samba and Windows?

Comment: not an answer but some thoughts and questions. Static, DHCP or mixed ip addressing and what device/devices working as a DHCP server? I have seen strange things like this with multiple dhcp sources, especially if vascilates between 2 different dhcp sources with the same dhcp settings. Everything seems to work but as it switches from one to other keeps togglng the private/public setting in windows. Just a thought...

Comment: @Greg, thanks, the DC is a Windows Server 2003 SP2 and the domain is using Kerberos. On the SLES12, as per SUSE docs in the link provided, Kerberos was configured and all the settings are the ones from the link.

Comment: @CreighChlopek thanks, it is a really good hint! ifconfig returns lo and eth0 but the machine has 4 cards and it should be configured as a bond; ifconfig -a returns eth0, eth1, eth2, eth3, lo and a usb0. The DHCP server is the DC and everything appears fine with the configuration. I'll configure the bond on the SLES to see what happens.

Comment: @Francisco: Accessing a share using an IP address uses NTLM, not Kerberos. I would speculate there is an NTLM mismatch.